# checking validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

Anyone can give me an advice for this, I have a problem on my jQuery login validation upon checking.

for example:

**1st problem:**
I submit my form and it has and error that will appear below my textbox and will show, if I submit again it will add 1 more error message below the first error message.

**Question No.1** 
How to get rid of those duplicate = p class="text-danger"?

```
here is my username textbox 
The username field is required. //error if empty
The username field is required. //2nd attempt of submit if textbox is empty

here is my password textbox
The password field is required. //error if empty
The username field is required. //2nd attempt of submit if textbox is empty
```

**2nd problem:**
I submit the form both empty and it will show the below message. Then when I put value on my "username text" it will removed the error message on my username which is correct. BUT If both empty and when I put value on my password textbox only it will removed BOTH error message which is wrong because it must removed ONLY the password error.

**Question No.2** How to fixed the error message when the username has a value and not empty.?

```
here is my username textbox 
The username field is required. //error if empty (if I put value on the username field it will removed this error message)

here is my password textbox
The password field is required. //error if empty (if i put value on the password field it will removed both error message)
```

login form:

```
<div class="form-group form-margin">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
         <?=form_input(['name'=>'username', 'class'=>'form-control error', 'autofocus'=>'autofocus', 'id'=>'username', 'placeholder'=>'Username']);?>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <?=form_password(['name'=>'password', 'class'=>'form-control error', 'id'=>'password', 'placeholder'=>'Password']);?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
        <?=form_button(['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control', 'id'=>'btnSubmit', 'content'=>'Sign In'])?>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $('#loginForm').attr('action');
    var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();

    $.each($('input'), function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            $(this).append().after('<p class="text-danger">The ' + this.id + ' field is required.</p>');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $('.text-danger').remove().after(this.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

**1st problem**. In your jquery code you have something like:

```
$(this).append().after('<p class="text-danger">The ' + this.id + ' field is required.</p>');
```

As function says, this will append new paragraph every time. It is better to have some hidden error message in html, and then use jquery to show/hide it than to use jquery to change html.

**2nd problem**. You're using something like:

```
$('.text-danger').remove().after(this.id);
```

If error occurs on first input, then both of your p-s with `.text-danger` will be affected. It is better to use something like:

```
$(this).parent().find('.text-danger').remove();
```

this should remove just `.text-danger` of current error.

Comment: I solved my problem Sir and post my answer your 2nd answer is correct also As I tried it :) thx also sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's not cleaner solution but that work.

Error message was not identified so I added a class to do it (error-for-xxx).

Error are removed before test to avoid duplicate.

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $('#loginForm').attr('action');
    var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();

    $.each($('input'), function(){
        // First remove error message already added
        $('.text-danger.error-for-' + this.id).remove();
        // Do empty check
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            $(this).after('<p class="text-danger error-for-' + this.id + '">The ' + this.id + ' field is required.</p>');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group form-margin">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
         <input type="text" name='username' class='form-control error' id='username'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="text" name='password' class='form-control error' id='password'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
       <button id="btnSubmit" class="'btn btn-primary form-control">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks nice answer Ma'am, I solved my problem also and I post my answer. I just used other trick :) Thankyou also

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem

First I add _underscore on my p tag ID since my p tag and my textbox have same ID. So I add _ to make my ID different with my textbox.

Then on my IF statement I add the remove class, before appending a new p tag to avoid error message duplication.

```
 $('#'+this.id+'_').remove();
```

on my Else statement I add the remove class targeting the ID of my p tag with _ underscore to remove there correspond error message that align to there textbox.

```
$.each($('input'), function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
        $('#'+this.id+'_').remove(); //adding this line
        $(this).append().after('<p class="text-danger" id="'+this.id+'_">The ' + this.id + ' field is required.</p>');
        //and adding underscore on my p class id.
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $('#'+this.id+'_').remove();  //adding this line
    }
});
```